# Can I use the glass from a gas fireplace insert on wood fireplace?

Tags: fireplace, glass

Can I use the glass from a gas fireplace insert and convert it into a glass door for a wood burning fireplace?

I visited Europe and observed that they had huge fireplaces with glass screens going up and down to load logs on the fire blew me away. All I see here are ugly metal boxes with tiny doors with tiny glass panels.

Is the glass from gas inserts resistant enough for high temperature from wood fire?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered on its own. Not all glass is created equally.

Comment: Can you give more detail on the glass you want to use?

Comment: I wanted to use glass like that as a door for my wood burning fireplace in the basement. Of course in some kind of metal frame with hinges... etc. I saw a 2 sided fireplace in a lodge in europe with 24x36" glass i thin metal frame that was sliding up by turning a crank. You load couple of logs and crank the glass dow. Don't know where to get a large piece of glass to fabricate that. The glass i found on line is usually small in size and expensive. Thought of buying old gas insert (kijiji - $100) and using glass from that.

Comment: Some bass inserts have this pretty heavy glass that you have to unbold in order to clean inside.

Comment: I know that "not all glass is created equally". The question is if the glass from gas insert is made the same as fire resistant glass from wood burning inserts. Or because the insert does not get as hot using gas, they do not use heat resistant glass for those inserts.?

Comment: Just found out that a glass off a gas inser should be heat resistant up to 500F. Question now is how hot can a wood fire get?